# Primitive Calculator in Python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I have written the following code which does what is supposed to do and passes the tests and time and memory limits. However, it takes 90% of the time limit. Is it anyway to speed this up?

Secondly, I have seen other solutions that seem to be more straightforward and do not build a list of all minimum operations for integers up to n. Isn't it true that in DP we are supposed to do that? In other words, aren't we supposed to always build a table from bottom up?

Lastly, how can I make the code more readable?

```
# Use Python 3

""" You're given a calculator with only 3 operations: (-1, //2, //3).
find the minimum number of operations and the sequence of numbers to
go from 1 to n"""
import sys

input = sys.stdin.read()
n = int(input)


def operations(n):
    """
    :param n: integer
    :return: The list of the minimum number of operations to reduce n to 1
    for each integer up to n. """
    lst = [0] * n
    for index in range(1, n):
        nodes = [1 + lst[index - 1]]
        for k in (2, 3):
            if (index + 1) % k == 0:
                nodes.append(1 + lst[((index + 1) // k) - 1])
        lst[index] = sorted(nodes)[0]

    return lst


master_sequence = list(enumerate(operations(n), 1))

end = master_sequence[-1]
minimum_operations = end[1]
sequence = []

while end != (1, 0):
    step = [item[0] for item in master_sequence if
            (end[1] - item[1]) == 1 and (end[0] - item[0] == 1 or end[0] % 
item[0] == 0)][0]
    sequence.append(step)
    end = master_sequence[step - 1]

print(minimum_operations)
for s in sequence[::-1]:
    print(s, end=' ')
print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

DP just means using sub-problem results to shorten the time/space complexity, so it often builds up but doesn't necessarily mean every value. Note: you could also solve this problem using a `heap` search, which wouldn't hit every node and I would imagine is pretty close to this in terms of timing and presumably less space.

A shorter approach using DP to the same result:

```
In []:
n = 10

# Define the operations and their condition for application:
ops = [(lambda x: True, lambda x: x-1),
       (lambda x: x%2==0, lambda x: x//2),
       (lambda x: x%3==0, lambda x: x//3)]

# Construct the operations count for all values up to `n`
min_ops = [0]*(n+1)
for i in range(2, n+1):
    min_ops[i] = min(min_ops[op(i)] for cond, op in ops if cond(i))+1

# Reconstruct the path
r = []
while n:
    r.append(n)
    n = min((op(n) for cond, op in ops if cond(n)), key=min_ops.__getitem__)

len(r)-1, r[::-1]

Out[]
(3, [1, 3, 9, 10])
```

Some quick timings for different `n`:

```
10: 22 µs ± 577 ns per loop
1000: 1.48 ms ± 12.3 µs per loop
10000: 15.3 ms ± 325 µs per loop
100000: 159 ms ± 2.81 ms per loop
```

When I ran your code for I got:

```
10: 15.7 µs ± 229 ns per loop
1000: 4.55 ms ± 318 µs per loop
10000: 27.1 ms ± 896 µs per loop
100000: 315 ms ± 7.13 ms per loop
```